# App Crashes on Startup with Xcode 15.0: Missing SwiftUI Symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm developing an app targeting iOS 15.0 and macOS 13.0. When I run it using Xcode 15.0 (RC1 or stable) on macOS 13.5.2, it crashes on startup—except when running on iOS 17. This occurs both on physical devices and simulators.

#### Error Details

Console throws a `dyld: Symbol not found` error, pointing at a SwiftUI symbol:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$ss5NeverO7SwiftUI10ShapeStyleACWP
```

It references paths for the iOS simulator and Mac shown below as examples:

```
Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 15.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
```

```
Expected in: [UUID omitted] /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Versions/A/SwiftUI
```

The complete stack trace is [here.](https://gist.github.com/d108/21fc31fea837e3690663fb18fd5fb55c)

#### Troubleshooting Steps

- Removed all Swift Package Manager dependencies to isolate the issue.
- The project runs successfully in Xcode 14.3.1.

#### Environment

- macOS: 13.5.2
- Xcode: 15.0 (also tried RC1)
- Command Line Tools: 15.0.0.0.1.1694021235

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

```swift
// When built with Xcode 15.0, conforming to ShapeStyle results in a startup crash.
enum CrashAppOnStart: ShapeStyle {
    case iOS15Crashes
    case iOS16Crashes
    case macOS13Crashes
}
```

Profiling with the App Launch Instrument shows that execution stalls before hitting `App.main(),` contributing to the crash.

*Has anyone experienced a similar issue or found a solution?*

Comment: Can you share some minimal reproducible code of your issue?

Comment: Sure, I've added code to reproduce the problem. Feel free to write up an answer.

Comment: I experience the same issue on macOS Sonoma RC and Xcode 15.0.

Comment: @GöranLilja, thanks for sharing that you're encountering the same issue on macOS Sonoma RC. Your input provides more context and might help others identify a pattern or solution more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

Implement `func resolve(in environment: EnvironmentValues) -> Self.Resolved`

Updated example:

```
enum CrashAppOnStart: ShapeStyle {
   case iOS15Crashes
   case iOS16Crashes
   case macOS13Crashes

   func resolve(in environment: EnvironmentValues) -> some ShapeStyle {
       Color.black
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution was already posted by @coffmark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this instance method:

```
func resolve(in environment: EnvironmentValues) -> Self.Resolved
```

The new `resolve(in:)` function has been added in iOS17 / macOS 14. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/resolve(in:)-mq46)